# Как из массива символов достать слово?

Tags: c, массивы

```
char a[20] = "SSID: Alex"
char b[10];
```

Необходимо слово Alex перенести в массив b. Вместо "Alex" могут быть как имена, так  и числа. Как это можно правильно реализовать?

Comment: Начните с того, что определите, что такое слово, какие его признаки. Нужно ли перенести второе слово, или слово после `SSID:`, или еще какое-то определение работает? Давайте начнем с **точного** ТЗ, без которого результат один - ХЗ. Ход за вами :)

Comment: Работаем по текущему ТЗ: Разделяете строку по пробелу, то что справа от него (и до конца строки) заносите в `b`. Так как ТЗ нечеткое, то можно (нужно) предусмотреть возможность задавать символ разделителя (потому что пробела может и не быть, а вот `:` вероятнее всего будет всегда, или нет... :) )

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Вы спешите. "По текущему ТЗ" можно просто скопировать в `b` строку `a+6`...

Comment: Это идет реализация приема сообщений от WS клиента в ESP32 (Wifi модуль). Клиент должен отправить настройки конфигурации. У каждого сообщения есть свой тэг: "SSID:", "PASS:" и т.д. Контроллер улавливает сообщение по тэгу, далее он должен извлечь из сообщения данные. К примеру: приходит сообщение "SSID: 123456" или "SSID: Name" -> программа должна записать в отдельный массив "123456" или "Name". Заранее известен только размер от начала сообщения до данных, которые мы хотим записать в переменную.

Comment: @Harry Хм ) Да, но у меня получился более универсальный вариант, хотя вы справились быстрее. Ждем вердикт заказчика ))

Comment: @Harry вы победили )

Comment: После тэга всегда будет : и пробел. А после пробела уже будет неизвестная часть, которую необходимо записать в переменную

Comment: мистер @Harry дал вам решение: копируйте подстроку начиная с `a+6` и до конца сообщения, или длины массива `b`

Comment: Если все тэги имеют одинаковую длину - то действительно берите `strcpy(b,a+6)`. Раз уж "*Заранее известен только размер от начала сообщения до данных, которые мы хотим записать в переменную*" - это и есть та шестерка... Но сразу встает вопрос - у вас некий контроллер анализирует тэг. Может, имеет смысл при этом анализе сразу выполнять и копирование?

Comment: Изначально данные приходят в виде const char*. После я сравниваю так: if(strncmp(payload_str, "SSID:", 6) == 0) {место для действий с сообщением}

Comment: Если это возможно, то было-бы очень удобно